# Extracting initials from a single string

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking to extract initials from a single textbox using Left, mid and other similar functions. The user enters their first, middle initial and last name; assuming spaces and a period after the middle initial. I need to ensure the initials extracted are uppercase, even if the text is entered in lowercase. Any assistance in a code that can accomplish this in VBA for Access would be appreciated. I am able to use the functions individually but am new to coding and am unsure how to string them together correctly.

```
Private Sub cmdGreeting_Click()
strOutput = Left(txtInput.Value, 1) & Mid(txtinput.value, 1) & Right(txtinput.value, 1)
lblOutput.Caption = strOutput
End Sub
```

This is as far as I have gotten and I know it's incorrect because I have no idea how to account for the 3 separate names.

Comment: Can you put some your data and output manually?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function based on regex. I'm sure someone will chip in to improve it, my VBA regex is rusty. It's based on the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/uuVyqV/1) where you can see examples of it matching. If you're not familiar with regex at all, they're frightening initially and it's beyond the scope of an answer to explain them.

However, it works by breaking any input into 5 strings:

1. Initial character of first name
2. remainder of name
3. Initial and . if present
4. Initial letter of last name
5. remainder of last name

Then, with some simple UCase and LCase, you can compile the require, formatted name. You may want to change the logic - you did imply there would be a middle initial but this assumes it won't always be there, and the dot after the initial may or may not be there.

**Note: you need to enable regex in Excel** - [instructions](http://www.simplysfdc.com/2017/02/how-to-run-regex-in-microsoft-excel.html)

```
Sub normalise()
    Debug.Print (proper("Reginald D. Hunter"))
    Debug.Print (proper("reginald D. hunter"))
    Debug.Print (proper("rEGINALD d. Hunter"))
    Debug.Print (proper("Reginald D Hunter"))
    Debug.Print (proper("Reginald Hunter"))
    Debug.Print (proper("Reginald      D.      Hunter"))
End Sub

Function proper(text) As String

    Dim regexMatch As Object
    Dim matches As Object

    With New RegExp
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z])([^ ]*)\s*([a-zA-Z]?[. ])?\s*([a-zA-Z])([^ ]*)"
        If .test(text) Then
            For Each regexMatch In .Execute(text)
                Set matches = regexMatch.SubMatches
            Next
        End If
    End With
    proper = UCase(matches(0)) + LCase(matches(1))
    If Trim(matches(2)) <> "" Then
        If InStr(matches(2), ".") Then
            proper = proper + " " + Trim(UCase(matches(2))) + " "
        Else
            proper = proper + " " + Trim(UCase(matches(2))) + ". "
        End If
    Else
        proper = proper + " "
    End If
    proper = proper + UCase(matches(3)) + LCase(matches(4))
End Function
```

Results in

Reginald D. Hunter
Reginald D. Hunter
Reginald D. Hunter
Reginald D. Hunter
Reginald Hunter
Reginald D. Hunter

**Edit: I misread the question** and if you just want initials then replace the last part of the function like so:

```
proper = UCase(matches(0))
If Trim(matches(2)) <> "" Then
    If InStr(matches(2), ".") Then
        proper = proper + Replace(Trim(UCase(matches(2))), ".", "")
    Else
        proper = proper + Trim(UCase(matches(2)))
    End If
End If
proper = proper + UCase(matches(3))
```

gives:

RDH
RDH
RDH
RDH
RH
RDH

Comment: Very nice, but as I understand OP, they want "RDH", not the propered name. Perhaps you can add this (should be trivial after the proper). -- And since you use late binding, the reference to RegExp is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I've been using for a while.  It will include the the initials of double-barreled names as well.

`?GetInitials("Darren Bartrup-Cook")` will return DBC.
`?GetInitials("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")` will return TQBFJOTLD.

```
Public Function GetInitials(FullName As String) As String

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim Ret As Object
    Dim RetItem As Object

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\b[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]* ?"
        Set Ret = .Execute(FullName)
        For Each RetItem In Ret
            GetInitials = GetInitials & UCase(RetItem.Submatches(0))
        Next RetItem
    End With

EXIT_PROC:
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function

ERR_HANDLE:
        'Add your own error handling here.
        'DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "mdl_GetInitials.GetInitials()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Function
```